# AWS Error : None of these Availability Zones contains a healthy target. Requests are being routed to all targets. in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a Application Load Balance in Aws.
I have created 2 EC2 and make them a group.
After that I add that group to the ALB with listener 80.

But when the system goes for healthy checks, it gives the error and shows that two registered EC2 are unhealthy.

The error is :

> None of these Availability Zones contains a healthy target. Requests
>   are being routed to all targets.
>
> Availability Zones:
>   **subnet-5691df0f - ap-northeast-1c,**
>   **subnet-97ae35e1 - ap-northeast-1a**

Please let me know the reason.

[AWS Related image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuxkr.png)

[AWS Related image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQZkZ.gif)

Answer (score 15):

I was running into this issue, and also getting a 504 Gateway timeout, and it ended up being this missing rule from [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-application-load-balancer.html#alb-sec-group).

1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
2. In the left navigation, choose Security Groups.
3. Choose the security group that your container instances use. If you created your container instances by using the Amazon ECS first run wizard, this security group may have the description, ECS Allowed Ports.
4. Choose the Inbound tab, and then choose Edit.
5. For Type, choose All traffic.
6. For Source, choose Custom, and then type the name of your Application Load Balancer security group that you created in Configure Security Groups. This rule allows all traffic from your Application Load Balancer to reach the containers in your tasks that are registered with your load balancer.
7. Choose Save to finish.

Comment: The step 3 cause me some time. For anyone may be confused like me, just go to the aws console. and choose the cluster that you are running.  In the network section, there is a Security groups area. The security group id is list under it. Just edit this sg as the document described and allow your ingress sg all traffic can be though.

Answer (score 7):

Check if your heath check parameters in target group is properly configured

protocol and port should be pointing to something where  response header return 200 ok

screenshot  [target group settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiqZe.png)

also, check if you EC2 heath check is ok or not and the Subnet you added to Alb should have at least 1 Ec2 running any of those subnets,

check the security group also should allow ALB to look for EC2

[AwS link 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geOiD.gif): https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEOnU.gif][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfwGm.gif)

[AWS Link 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geOiD.gif)

Comment: thank you very much. Basically, I have uploaded 1 api which works with POST Request. SO, there are some data on payload.

the api is /{name}. So, how can I test this..


Spring application.
/place
post the place information in the DB.

So, how response header returns 200.

Comment: Thanks. I individually tested two EC2 with 80 port and called the api with proper payload. It is OK. But when I call those two ec2 as a group from ALB, it shows gateway time out 504 error.

It seems little be confusing to me.

Comment: Are all of the Ec2 instance and your ALB reside inside same VPC. and does the security group of EC2 and ALB is same ? 

can you share a screenshot of your elb setup you can hide the private data and name/ ip of ec2

Comment: Please check the two links from parent post and two links from your post. 
I have link restriction. SO, I did this ......

Hope it will make you understand to help me.

Comment: In image i can see your both Ec2 But Need image of your load balancer security group and setup .

Comment: Load balancer security group inbound -
HTTP (80)  TCP (6)  80 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: HTTPS (443) TCP (6) 443 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: -------
outbound -
ALL Traffic  ALL  ALL  0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Please let me know if you need anything.

Comment: I have seen all images from here it looks okay with the security group and all . but you are using path patter in your alb  as you have used /loacation 

which is sending traffic to your target group is it right ?

Have you checked it with default means no path (try simple then go complex )

if you can show your successful result from any of ec2  response header

Comment: Finally, I managed the problem. Thanks Biswajit Mohanty for you nice support. 
There was actually security group issue. Anyway, I have modified lots of things here. Now its up and running.

Again thanks..

Comment: Glad to see that you made it. :D

Comment: hi, I have another issue. Could you please have a look on it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223737/how-to-create-load-balancer-for-non-web-application-in-aws-i-have-one-java-stan

Comment: @Rashed Please post your solution on SO.  Please remember that others are trying to solve problems also.

Comment: @BiswajitMohanty  The links you posted here don't work.  Please use links that will last for years on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar issue while learning to setup load balancer for my EC2 instance.

It turns out that under Target Groups:

the "path" under the "Health Check" tab was not registered although it showed the correct value "/".

Therefore I just edited the path value(by clicking the "edit health check") to "/" and saved it again just so that the system can register that value. (you could also try saving it to some other value, say "/health", first and then saving it back to "/")

This seemed to fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hi all I just encountered the same issue and the solution is a setting in the ALB (Application Load Balancer) itself

Make sure the ALB AZ matches your instance AZ here is a screenshot of the setting.  I am using us-east-1a and us-eas-1e for my instance.  So my ALB setting for AZ should match that, click on the "Edit Subnets" button to edit your AZ on your ALB

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that communication is allowed at security group level between your load balancer and your targets.

From AWS 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-update-security-groups.html

> You must ensure that your load balancer can communicate with registered targets on both the listener port and the health check port [...] you must verify that the security groups associated with the load balancer allow traffic on the new port in both directions.

For example, a simple way to portray the rules you would require if you have a PUBLIC FACING load balancer in security group sg-001 and three EC2 targets in another security group sg-002 is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add new AZs by clicking on the Edit Subnet under the Load Balancer description.