# AWS Error : None of these Availability Zones contains a healthy target. and status is "outofservice" in AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento

```
Ping Target - HTTP:80/
Timeout - 5 seconds
Interval - 30 seconds
Unhealthy threshold - 2
Healthy threshold - 10
```

I created a load balancer and assigned it one of the running EC2 instance. After creation, I navigated to Target Group section in the AWS Console under Load Balancing and when I selected the target group that was assigned to the load balancer, it shows registered instance status as `"Unhealthy"` and there was a message above registered instance panel that says:

> None of these Availability Zones contains a healthy target.

why does my registered instance status as `"Unhealthy"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an answer to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086262/aws-error-none-of-these-availability-zones-contains-a-healthy-target-requests)

It might be that you are missing a rule as mentioned in the link above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Fix the issue, i changed Ping Protocol from https to ssl .. it worked !

Go to Health Check  --> click on Edit Health Check -- > change Ping protocol from HTTPS to SSL
Ping Target SSL:443
Timeout 5 seconds
Interval    30 seconds
Unhealthy Threshold 5
Healthy Threshold   10

Comment: Great :) You can select it as an answer if it helped you.